# VirtualBox Freezes In Fullscreen Mode (Win11 on Ubuntu)

Tags: virtualbox, guest-additions, windows-11

1. i installed virtualbox(6.1.38_Ubuntur153438) on ubuntu(Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) then
2. i installed windows 11 on that then
3. i installed guest additions

issue : everything is ok but when i trying to entring the fullscreen mode virtualbox freezes , every thing freezes